# How to call a variable of a function in a different component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-react-ui

I have a function that creates a Dropdown list using kendo react from a list 'lista'. Each element of the list is a dictionary with a key 'Region' and a value 'Tile'.

```
function Menu (Auser){
let lista = []
// Here I have a series of loops that read lista and tiles using a command similar to lista.push({Region:users.userList[i].locations[j].region, Tile:users.userList[i].locations[j].tile});

const [state, setState] = useState({
    value: lista[0],
});

const handleChange = (event) => {
setState({
    value: event.target.value,
}); 
}
  
return (
    <form>
    <p>Avaliable regions</p>
    <div>
    Selected Value: {JSON.stringify(state.value.Tile)} // Here I print my variable of interest
    </div>
    <DropDownList className="dropdown-content" data={lista} 
    textField="Region"
    dataItemKey="Tile"
    value={state.value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    />
</form>
);
}
export default Menu;
```

In order to create, and update, another component in my App.js file, I need to pass the variable `state.value.Tile` which is the 'Tile' of the element selected in the Dropdown list, in the Menu function, to another component in App.js. The problem is that I don't know how to call or extract this variable from the Menu function.

```
import Menu from './components/menu';
import SecondElement from './components/secondelement';
class App extends Component { // This is an example of my structure

  render (){
    return (
          <header className="App-header">
            <h3>
              Hello world!
            </h3>
            <Menu Auser={user.attributes.name}/>
            <SecondElement SelectedTile={state.value.Tile}/> // I should be able to put the variable state.value.Tile, from the Menu function here.
      )}
      </Authenticator>  
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am basically new to React so I've been having problems and I don't understand several things, any help you can give me will be appreciated.

Comment: 1.put your handleChange function in the class App, and pass it as props in the <Menu /> component
2. pass state (or itemSelected)  as props to the <SecondElement />

Answer (score -1):

```
// App.JS

import {useEffect} from 'react';
import Menu from './components/menu';
import SecondElement from './components/secondelement';
class App = (props) { // This is an example of my structure

  const [selectedTile, setSelectedTile] = useEffect(null);
  
  OnTileUpdated = (tile) => setSelectedTile(tile)

    return (
          <header className="App-header">
            <h3>
              Hello world!
            </h3>
            <Menu handleTile={onTileUpdated} Auser={user.attributes.name}/>
            <SecondElement SelectedTile={selectedTile}/> 
      )}
      </Authenticator>  
    );
}

export default App;

//Menu JS

function Menu ({Auser, handleTile}){
let lista = []

const [state, setState] = useState({
    value: lista[0],
});

const handleChange = (event) => {
setState({
    value: event.target.value,
}); 
handleTile(event.target.value)
}
  
return (
    <form>
    <p>Avaliable regions</p>
    <div>
    Selected Value: {JSON.stringify(state.value.Tile)} // Here I print my variable of interest
    </div>
    <DropDownList className="dropdown-content" data={lista} 
    textField="Region"
    dataItemKey="Tile"
    value={state.value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    />
</form>
);
}
export default Menu;
```